# why tags land into gitlab in a detatched state?

Tags: git, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, git-tag

from git log

```
hash1 (HEAD -> mybranch, tag: 1.123.22)
hash2 (origin/mybranch, origin/HEAD)
```

commiting the tag back to

```
git tag -d 1.123.22
git tag -a 1.123.22 -m "somemessage"
git push -u someuser@gitrepo mybranch --tags
```

now back in gitlab the tags doesn't land on the branch but have commit hash in some detatched state from the branch and their parent is a commit from another branch.

How to push the tags back to the mybranch with my version changes in other files instead of a detatched commit?

EDIT pardon me, yes there was no '-branch' parameter, but rest seems to be accurate

When trying

```
git push --tags --set-upstream someuser@gitrepo mybranch
```

The only difference was that the output was

```
 * [new tag]           1.3.42 -> 1.3.42
```

instead of

```
Everything up to date
```

But the tag lands into gitlab with a commit on a detatched state

EDIT2 this is not really about the tags from what I see the commit is also having problems reaching mybranch:

```
+ git commit -m 'message'
[mybranch somehash] message
 4 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
+ git branch -vv
* mybranch somehash[origin/mybranch: ahead 1] message
+ git remote -v
origin  myrepo (fetch)
origin  myrepo (push)
+ git push --set-upstream myrepo mybranch
Everything up-to-date
```

however despite the message, the changes seem to be pushed. 
Checking branches locally:

```
git branch --list
* develop
```

Comment: Is `-branch` supposed to be a git push argument ? I don't find it into documentation.
`git push --tags -u someuser@gitrepo mybranch` should work. Could you try with this syntax ?

Comment: I double-checked, and at least in my tests it appears the `push` command as written will not run.  Please update the question with the exact command you used, so we can know what might have resulted.  Also, please provide whatever commands and output show that "the tags doesn't land on the branch but have commit has in some detached state ..."

Comment: Note also that if you supply a *tag name* to `git checkout`, you *always* get a detached HEAD by definition.

Comment: torek ok, how to make the commit that comes back with the tag to the repo back on my development branch and not detatched HEAD?

Comment: If git was to come back with the branch, it would mean you have an outdated version of the branch. Git tags are pointers to a single commit, just like branches are, and therefore it shows as a detached head

Comment: ok, however when I strip the tags and just try to commit back to the repo I get the same issue- commit doesn't land on the branch, please see the new output I have listed, despite it says everything up to date, not everything is up to date, there were numerous changes and the commit actually lands on the repo, but its also in a detatched state

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a message after applying your push command?

The documentation does not list the `-branch` argument you are using:

> git push [--all | --mirror | --tags] [--follow-tags] [--atomic] [-n |
>   --dry-run] [--receive-pack=]
>                     [--repo=] [-f | --force] [-d | --delete] [--prune] [-v | --verbose]
>                     [-u | --set-upstream] [--push-option=]
>                     [--[no-]signed|--signed=(true|false|if-asked)]
>                     [--force-with-lease[=[:]]]
>                     [--no-verify] [ [...]]

Can you try the following and let me know if it works?

`git push --tags --set-upstream someuser@gitrepo mybranch`

(instead of `--set-upstream` you could use `-u`, used verbose version to increase readability)

Comment: using both --set-upstream and -u can mess things up? I have just tried it and the result is exactly the same, 'everything up to date', the tag lands in the repo along with the commit but its in a detatched state and doesn't belong to any branch

Comment: No, that shouldn‘t make the difference. I used —set-upstream for the sole purpose that a future reader of this answer does not have to look up what -u stands for. My correction is removing the -branch command.

Comment: yes I have wrongly wrote it in stackoverflow, the command didnt used the -branch parameter only the name of the branch